# Eigenvectors/values Eigen, I don't need them all

Tags: c++, eigen

Eigen does a full diagonalization, but I don't want to write them all and then crop the matrix/vectors to the first x columns/elements, where x is the maximum number of eigenvectors/values I want.

How can i just store the first x Eigenvectors/values inside the matrix/array I create beforehand from the matrix.eigenvectors()/eigenvalues()?

Comment: Do you specifically want the X *largest* eigenvalues?

Comment: related (same operation, different language and library): https://stackoverflow.com/q/12167654/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt I just need to copy the first x eigenvalues of the eigen full diagonalization into a matrix. I know how to wirte krilov based algorithms. This time I need to fully diagonalize. Just don't want to allocate more memory than needed.

Comment: "first" is not very meaningful, because it depends on an unspecified ordering.  And you are asking for not a full decomposition, but only a subset of eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs

Comment: @BenVoigt I ask you to use eigen before replying

Comment: You're missing Ben's point. You say you want the "first" x eigenvectors/values.   That's an ambiguous description.  Can your matrix have complex eigenvalues or are they all real?  If they are all real, do you mean the x largest eigenvalues?  The x smallest?   the x with largest absolute value?  The x eigenvalues closest to 42?  Or what?  Not all algorithms *can* extract a subset of eigenvalues (you have to do it after, if needed) and any algorithm which can does so to meet some criterion - so YOU have to specify a criterion you need met, to pick an algorithm.